# how to allow f() to take decimal values

Tags: python, django

Firstly, I need to sum the student mark before converting it to a percentage. So Ive managed to sum up their mark and somehow managed to convert it to percentage thru this method.

```
students = MarkAtt.objects.values('studName__VMSAcc').annotate(mark=Sum('attendance'), percentage=(F('mark')/1100) * 100)
```

However, I realised that the F() does not take decimal value. It only takes the integer value. This would cause an error to my percentage calculation if the value 'mark' is less than 100.

For example: 600/1100 = 0.54545 then it will only take 0 to multiple with 100. And output '0' instead of 54%.

How do I allow the function take decimal value?

EDITED:

```
def file_load_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="studFinal-attendance.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Student Name', 'Attendance'])

    students = MarkAtt.objects.values('studName__VMSAcc').annotate(mark=Sum('attendance'),
    percentage=(Cast('mark', FloatField())/1100) * 100)

    #convert the students query set to a values list as the writerow expects a list/tuple
    students = students.values_list('studName__VMSAcc','percentage')

    for student in students:
        writer.writerow(student)
    return response
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`Cast`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) to to specify to what type it should be converted, and thus let Django do the inference:

```
from django.db.models import FloatField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

students = MarkAtt.objects.values('studName__VMSAcc').annotate(
    mark=Sum('attendance'),
    percentage=(Cast('mark', FloatField())/1100) * 100
)
```

and you can convert it to a decimal field at the end to use a specific number of digits:

```
from django.db.models import DecimalField, FloatField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

students = MarkAtt.objects.values('studName__VMSAcc').annotate(
    mark=Sum('attendance'),
    percentage=Cast(
        (Cast('mark', FloatField())/1100) * 100,
        output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    )
)
```

Comment: @Puteri: If I run this locally with sample data, I get for `students.first()['percentage']` as value `Decimal('0.09')`. Can you look what you get as percentage?

Comment: the template is displaying 54.5% while the exported data is displaying 54.54545454.

Comment: would u mind looking at my another problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58204181/import-data-into-sqlite-database-with-foreign-key-django