# import data into sqlite database with foreign key django

Tags: python, django

I want to import student's name list to database with one foreign key which is the class infomation.

Namelist Model.py:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
program = models.CharField(max_length=10)
classGrp = models.ForeignKey('GroupInfo', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

the data in the namelist is like this:

```
id      name            program     classGrp    

1   ABHISHEK SINGH  CE1 1
```

GroupInfo Model.py:

```
class GroupInfo(models.Model):
    classGrp = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

The data in the groupInfo is like this:

```
id      classGrp   day

1   FEP1    Tues    

2   FSP1    Wed
```

When i import the namelist data, eg as below:

```
id  name    program     classGrp

137 Dummy   FP      2
```

It does not store 2, which is the classGrp. When i check the detail of the classGrp at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin: The classGrp is in dropdownlist displaying the classgr ( FEP1,FSP1) instead of the ID (1,2).

VIEW.PY:

```
def import_studName(request):
    template = "import_stud.html"

    prompt = {
        'order' : 'Kindly ensure that the order of CSV should be id, name, program, classGrp'
    }

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, template, prompt)
    csv_file = request.FILES['file']

    if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        messages.error(request, 'This is not a csv file')

    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)

    next(io_string) 
    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
        if column[3] != '':
                classGrp = GroupInfo.objects.get(pk = (column[3]))
        else: 
            classGrp = GroupInfo.objects.get()
        _, created = Namelist.objects.update_or_create(
            id=column[0],
            name=column[1],
            program=column[2],
            classGrp = column[3]
        )


    context = {}    
    return render(request,template, context)
```

And that is the reason why it does not import the classGrp data which is 2.

How do i import a foreign key id to the database?

ERROR MESSAGE:

Cannot assign "'2'": "Namelist.classGrp" must be a "GroupInfo" instance.

Comment: Why column 8? The classGrp ID is in column 3. (But no, the fact that the admin displays the group name as you requested is not the reason why your view does not import the group data.)

Comment: Oh i have other attributes and didnt change accordingly. it should be id 4.

Comment: So may i know what is the problem that it does not import the group data?

Comment: @Puteri where do you pass the GroupInfo instance (`classGrp` in your snippet) to the `NameList.update_or_create` call ?

Comment: I have editted my code. classGrp = column[4]. And the error is " 
Cannot assign "'2'": "Namelist.classGrp" must be a "GroupInfo" instance."

Comment: thanks @brunodesthuilliers for asking me tht questin. Manage to solve the question

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve my own question. My mistake was that i didnt call classgrp in the namelist.update_or_create.

Here's the updated answer:

```
     for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):

    if column[3] != '':
            classGrp = GroupInfo.objects.get(pk = (column[3]))
    else: 
        classGrp = GroupInfo.objects.get()
    _, created = Namelist.objects.update_or_create(
        id=column[0],
        name=column[1],
        program=column[2],
        classGrp = GroupInfo.objects.get(pk = (column[3]))

            )
```